# Why systemd cannot mount swap and local partitions after Kubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: boot, partitioning, upgrade, kubuntu, systemd

I performed upgrade from Kubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 and it cannot boot now, I can get recovery console from systemd. systemd complains that it cannot mount swap and local partitions, because of timeout waiting for device.

```
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.device/start timed out.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home/marcin/Kelvatek.
-- Subject: Unit home-marcin-Kelvatek.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit home-marcin-Kelvatek.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
-- Subject: Unit dns-clean.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dns-clean.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: home-marcin-Kelvatek.mount: Job home-marcin-Kelvatek.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
lis 10 13:16:06 marcin-HP-ProBook-6570b systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c4415bd\x2d91c9\x2d4434\x2dbace\x2dbe02ee0a8082.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
```

There are some more similar errors.

I've checked that uuids of partitions in /etc/fstab are correct. It also looks like kernel has all configuration options required by systemd. What is wrong then?

Some information on my system follows.

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=65f0c8b8-f351-4ad8-aab7-da5093864282 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /sda6 was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=b189aa58-3e5f-40fb-a0ab-fbf502975afd /sda6           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /sda7 was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082 /sda7           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082 /home/marcin/Kelvatek           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2ecf9719-2fbd-4e40-bd3f-8832e07c4940 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="36BA6BB6BA6B7173" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="C43A48D13A48C1E2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="HP_TOOLS" UUID="AA18-B4E7" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2ecf9719-2fbd-4e40-bd3f-8832e07c4940" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="b189aa58-3e5f-40fb-a0ab-fbf502975afd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-07"
/dev/sda8: UUID="65f0c8b8-f351-4ad8-aab7-da5093864282" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9417f9fb-08"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4C40-5FAD" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="91f72d24-01"
```

lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                        
└─sdb1 vfat            4C40-5FAD                            /media/pen
sr0                                                        
sda                                                        
├─sda4 vfat   HP_TOOLS AA18-B4E7                            
├─sda2 ntfs            C43A48D13A48C1E2                    
├─sda7 ext4            0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082
├─sda5 swap            2ecf9719-2fbd-4e40-bd3f-8832e07c4940
├─sda3                                                      
├─sda1 ntfs   SYSTEM   36BA6BB6BA6B7173                    
├─sda8 ext4            65f0c8b8-f351-4ad8-aab7-da5093864282 /
└─sda6 ext4            b189aa58-3e5f-40fb-a0ab-fbf502975afd
```

udevadm info /dev/sda7

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7
N: sda7
S: disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HTS727550A9E364_J3320082GY2ARA-part7
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca68acd3791-part7
S: disk/by-partuuid/9417f9fb-07
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part7
S: disk/by-uuid/0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1-part7 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HTS727550A9E364_J3320082GY2ARA-part7 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/9417f9fb-07 /dev/disk/by-uuid/0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082 /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca68acd3791-part7
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda7
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda7
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: ID_ATA=1
E: ID_ATA_DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_APM=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_APM_CURRENT_VALUE=128
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_APM_ENABLED=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM_ENABLED=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ENABLED=0
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ENHANCED_ERASE_UNIT_MIN=124
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_ERASE_UNIT_MIN=122
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SECURITY_FROZEN=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART=1
E: ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_SMART_ENABLED=1
E: ID_ATA_ROTATION_RATE_RPM=7200
E: ID_ATA_SATA=1
E: ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN1=1
E: ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN2=1
E: ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE=1
E: ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE_ENABLED=1
E: ID_BUS=ata
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=0c4415bd-91c9-4434-bace-be02ee0a8082
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
E: ID_MODEL=Hitachi_HTS727550A9E364
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Hitachi\x20HTS727550A9E364\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:0
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=7
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=525309952
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=437495808
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0x83
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=9417f9fb-07
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=9417f9fb
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1f_2-ata-1
E: ID_REVISION=JF3OA0E0
E: ID_SERIAL=Hitachi_HTS727550A9E364_J3320082GY2ARA
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=J3320082GY2ARA
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_WWN=0x5000cca68acd3791
E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5000cca68acd3791
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=7
E: PARTN=7
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6825467
```

Comment: It turns out that I have similar problem to: http://superuser.com/questions/850738/systemd-cant-mount-partition

The workaround for mounting partition later does not work - partition is not mounted, but at least system fully boots up. Unfortunately it turned out that there are more problems with Kubuntu 16.10 - new kernel has recursive exception problems, so at the minute I fall backed to kernel 3.13.0-24 and manual mounting of partition.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10.

**First possible solution**

I found a probable solution in [systemd issue 3446](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3446) where [Iztok Jeras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963756/iztok-jeras) just installed udev (`sudo apt install -y udev`).

It didn't fix it for me permanently. The next boot was successfull after I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure udev` but I ran into that again the next boot time.

If installing `udev`doesn't work for you either you may consider participating in the [open systemd issue on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1463023).

**Second possible solution**

Add `selinux=1 enforcing=0` to yout kernel parameter.
There seem to be a bug in some cases where this helped (it didn't for me though)

I have currently the same (unsolved) symptoms and can't fix them on my system.
It seems that there could be many reasons for these error messages (crypto-setup seems to be one of them but not relevant in your case).

The strange thing is that booting works one of ten times in my case. So this might be a dependency issue in my case.

Comment: I had also googled it, but it did not fix my problem. Generally udev seems to misfunction on my computer, recently sound card and webcam stopped to work. To fix this I had to add another workaround - add appropriate modules with drivers to /etc/modules, because they were not automatically loaded by udev.